# Yang-Lee article on phase transition (1952): possible problem in lemma demonstration

Tags: phase-transition, critical-phenomena, condensation

I'm studying the first article of Yang-Lee on phase transition

C.N.Yang  and  T.D.Lee,   Physical  Review,   ”Statistical  Theory  of  Equations  of  State  and  Phase Transitions.  I. Theory of Condensation”, 1952. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.87.404

and I can't find the solution to one problem. If you go to the demonstration of the second lemma (that states $\exists \mbox{ } \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{W_i}\log{\mathcal{Q}_i}$, where $W_i$ is a cube of linear dimension $2^iL$) in Appendix I the conclusion is the following: for the "Squeeze theorem" we have

$lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{W_j} \log{\mathcal{Q}_j} -  \frac{1}{W_i} \log{\mathcal{Q}_i}$ = 0

Hence the lemma. ($W_j$ is the cube formed by $8^{j-i}$ smaller cube $W_i$)

Notice that we want to prove the existence of the limit of one of the terms of the difference. 
Now my point is: if the limit of the difference exists, and this is what is stated above, it's not sure that the limits of the terms exist their selves.

So how do we conclude the thesis from the existence of the limit of the difference? I can't see it and for them it is obvious.

The prove of this lemma is fundamental for the demonstration of the first theorem that is the basis of the theory of condensation by Yang and Lee.

I'm sorry if the question is not perfectly clear, in order to understand it you must read Yang Lee demonstration, even just for the notation.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Use their bounds to show that this sequence is Cauchy and hence convergent. (I don't have their paper with me, but I am pretty sure that's the way it goes; at least that's one of the two classical ways of doing it in more modern versions of the proof.)

Comment: Yes I think this is the best justification at all. Thank you very much!